# pyramid: constructe route_url without request object

Tags: pyramid, web-frameworks, parser-generator

I use yapps to generate a parser for a LaTex-ish language (for example to translate stuff like `\begin{itemize}` to the corresponding `<ul>`-Tags) within pyramid. One command (i.e. `\ref{SOMEID}`) should construct a route via a call of `route_url` (or `route_path`) and pass the id to it. Since this call happens deep in the code that was generated by yapps and the grammar that I defined, I don't see any possibility to pass a request object to it.

Is there some sort of global request object? Or, since I foresee that I shouldn't use it, is there a possibility to construct a route (that depends on a parameter) without a request object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`route_url` requires both a request and a registry (`request.registry`). It generates urls relative to the request, and it accesses the list of all routes and other settings from the registry. Thus, you *must* generate a dummy request with parameters you care about. For example:

```
from pyramid.request import Request

request = Request.blank('/', base_url='https://example.com/prefix')
request.registry = config.registry
```

Now you can store this request anywhere, it's good to go representing everything about your site: the hostname/port (`example.com:443`), the prefix your app is mounted at (`/prefix`), the uri scheme (`https`).

If you need to get this deep down into your code you may have to make it a global or attach it to some context/registry that you have available, but what I've shown is how to make the request that you require.

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't know the blank-function. I used `get_current_registry()` from `pyramid.threadlocal` to get the registry and then could just call `route_path`.